# Зачем нужно свойство orientation в GridLayout?

Tags: android

В документации написано, что это свойство не используется в GridLayout, но во-первых оно там есть, а во-вторых его изменение оказывает эффект на вложенные элементы:

[image: orientation vertical]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации вполне однозначно [сказано](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html#attr_android:orientation):

> The orientation property is not used during layout. It is only used to allocate row and column parameters when they are not specified by its children's layout paramters. GridLayout works like LinearLayout in this case; putting all the components either in a single row or in a single column - depending on the value of this flag. In the horizontal case, a columnCount property may be additionally supplied to force new rows to be created when a row is full. The rowCount attribute may be used similarly in the vertical case. The default is horizontal.

Здесь указано, что данный параметр не не используется в виджете, а имеет несколько другое свойство. То есть, свойство влияет не на компоновку лэйаута, а на вложенные в него элементы, что и наблюдается на ваших скриншотах - параметр влияет на виджеты в каждой ячейке (если их несколько), а не на порядок ячеек.

Принцип такой, что каждая ячейка `GridLayout` ведет себя, как `LinearLayout` (если не указано иное) и именно для этого вложенного лэйаута и указывается свойство (точнее для всех ячеек разом).
На ваших скриншотах все происходит именно так, как написано в документации.

PS: Стоит читать документацию полностью, а не первую строчку.